# htaccess permanent redirection with some changes in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying, with very no success, to redirect from one URL to another one and have some changes in the structure of that.

What I'd like to do is to redirect this:

```
www.mydomain.com/blog/category/name-of-article/123456 (where 123456 is the ID of the article)
```

to this:

```
www.mydomain.com/news/name-of-the-article/
```

As you can see I have removed the string **"category"**, I have renamed **"blog"** into **"news"** and lastly I have removed the **trailing ID** of the article.

I have also tried a htaccess generator online, but here also, no success, because I am not able to address **"blog/category"** part towards **"news"**.

Any hint? Or online resource?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any .htaccess in `/blog/` directory you can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?blog/category/([^/]+)/.*$ /news/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not able to test it right now, because the system manager has closed all accesses to the server until tomorrow morning. I will let you know as soon as I can test it. Thanks again